# Criar combo com os meses para filtrar no calendário

Tags: php, html

Pretendo criar um filtro por mês no calendário.

**Código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registo Refeições</title>
    <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

         $dates = date('Y/m/d');
         $hoje = getdate(strtotime($dates));       
         $mes = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');
         $ultimoDia = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,
                                       $hoje['mon'],
                                       $hoje['year']);


        $primeiraSemana = (($hoje['wday'] + 1) -
                          ($hoje['mday'] - ((int)($hoje['mday'] / 6) * 7))) % 7;

    ?>

    <style>

        td { color: #000000;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Estamos em <?= $hoje['year'] ?> de <?= $mes[$hoje["mon"]] ?></h1>
    <p><?= sprintf('Hoje é dia <strong>%0d / %0d</strong>.',
                   $hoje['mday'], $hoje['mon'])
    ?></p>

    <table >
    <caption><h1><center><strong><?= $mes[$hoje["mon"]] ?> - <?= $hoje['year'] ?></strong></center></h1></caption>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Domingo</th>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Segunda</th>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Terça</th>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Quarta</th>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Quinta</th>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Sexta</th>
            <th bgcolor="silver" align="center">Sábado</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php

        for($semana = 0; $semana < $primeiraSemana; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
        for($dia = 1; $dia < $ultimoDia; ++$dia) {
            if( $semana > 6 ) {
                $semana = 0;
                echo '</tr><tr>';
            }

            echo "<td bgcolor='#F5F5F5' align='center' data-semana=\"$semana\"><center><font size='2px'/>";
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][dia]";    echo"' value='$dia'> $dia<center>
<p><input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][OpcaoA]"; echo"' value='Peq. Almoço'> Peq. Almoço 
<p><input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoB]"; echo"' value='Almoço'> Almoço 
<p><input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoB]"; echo"' value='Almoço Dieta'> Almoço (Dieta)
<p><input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoC]"; echo"' value='Lanche'> Lanche
<p><input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoD]"; echo"' value='Jantar'> Jantar
<p><input type='checkbox' name='"; echo "arrachar[$dia][opcaoD]"; echo"' value='Jantar Dieta'> Jantar (Dieta)</td>";
            ++$semana;
        }

        for(; $semana < 7; ++$semana) {
            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }

        ?>

    <?php


if( !empty( $_POST['dias'] ) ) {
    foreach( $_POST['dias'] as $key => $values ) {
        echo "<br />Semana $key<br />";
        foreach( $values as $dias ) {
            echo "$dias<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Marcar">
       </form>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Pretendo criar uma combo com os meses e ao selecionar o calendário modifica para o mês escolhido.
Além de criar a combo, preciso de corrigir o meu código, uma vez que o mês de Março tem 31 dias e o meu calendário só está a montar 30 dias.

Comment: Sim! Mas qual o problema que você está esbarrando? Tudo funciona, você só não conseguiu criar um combo com os meses e ao selecionar o calendário modifica para o mês escolhido?

Comment: Sim, é isso @Fabiano Monteiro, tudo está funcionando mesmo a inserir na base de dados, falta me isso

Comment: Eu montei um calendário(input) com JQuery para montar o filtro e mudar o calendário html, porém seu calendário está montando dias a menos para os meses escolhidos. Posso até responder a sua pergunta com um filtro adicionado, mas seu código precisará de revisões para meses futuro.

Comment: Então se puderes coloca o código para o filtro e indica onde preciso de fazer uma revisão ao meu código para os meses futuros. Agradeço a tua ajuda

Comment: Por exemplo. Teu código monta o mês de Março com 30 dias, mas o mês tem 31 dias.

Comment: Ainda não tinha reparado nisso, como posso colocar o calendário a funcionar correto

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e acrescente mais este problema, se alguém puder olhar. Quando eu puder, vejo aqui novamente.

Comment: OK, vou editar a pergunta, mas quando tiver um tempinho para me ajudar eu agradeço a sua ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, utilizei como base uma função, que pode ser vista em: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php#76520)

Espero que você avance a partir deste código que deixo aqui.

Utilizando mini calendário em JQuery, muito mais rico, abrindo a possibilidade de também escolher o dia. Ficará à seu critério. De qualquer forma,o calendáro HTML é montado sem erro, de acordo com o mês do ano escolhido.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registo Refeições</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        //////////////////////////
            $(function() {
                $( "#date_picker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
                });
            });
        ////////////////
        })
    </script>

    <form name="form1" id="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        <input type="text" name="data" id="date_picker">  
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php

# PHP Calendar (version 2.3), written by Keith Devens

function generate_calendar($year, $month, $days = array(), $day_name_length = 3, $month_href = NULL, $first_day = 0, $pn = array()){
    $first_of_month = gmmktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);

    #remember that mktime will automatically correct if invalid dates are entered
    # for instance, mktime(0,0,0,12,32,1997) will be the date for Jan 1, 1998
    # this provides a built in "rounding" feature to generate_calendar()

    $day_names = array(); #generate all the day names according to the current locale
    for($n=0,$t=(3+$first_day)*86400; $n<7; $n++,$t+=86400) #January 4, 1970 was a Sunday
        $day_names[$n] = ucfirst(gmstrftime('%A',$t)); #%A means full textual day name

        $mes_pt = array('', 'Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro');

    list($month, $year, $month_name, $weekday) = explode(',',gmstrftime('%m,%Y,%B,%w',$first_of_month));
    $weekday = ($weekday + 7 - $first_day) % 7; #adjust for $first_day
    //$title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($month_name)).'&nbsp;'.$year;  #note that some locales don't capitalize month and day names

    $title   = htmlentities(ucfirst($mes_pt[(int)$month])).'&nbsp;'.$year;

    #Begin calendar. Uses a real <caption>. See http://diveintomark.org/archives/2002/07/03
    @list($p, $pl) = each($pn); @list($n, $nl) = each($pn); #previous and next links, if applicable
    if($p) $p = '<span class="calendar-prev">'.($pl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($pl).'">'.$p.'</a>' : $p).'</span>&nbsp;';
    if($n) $n = '&nbsp;<span class="calendar-next">'.($nl ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($nl).'">'.$n.'</a>' : $n).'</span>';
    $calendar = '<table class="calendar">'."\n".
        '<caption class="calendar-month">'.$p.($month_href ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($month_href).'">'.$title.'</a>' : $title).$n."</caption>\n<tr>";

    if($day_name_length){ #if the day names should be shown ($day_name_length > 0)
        #if day_name_length is >3, the full name of the day will be printed
        //foreach($day_names as $d)
            //$calendar .= '<th abbr="'.htmlentities($d).'">'.htmlentities($day_name_length < 4 ? substr($d,0,$day_name_length) : $d).'</th>';

            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Domingo</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Segunda</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Terça</th>";
            $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Quarta</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Quinta</th>";
            $calendar .= "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Sexta</th>";
            $calendar .=  "<th bgcolor='silver' align='center'>Sábado</th>";

        $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
    }

    if($weekday > 0) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.$weekday.'">&nbsp;</td>'; #initial 'empty' days
    for($day=1,$days_in_month=gmdate('t',$first_of_month); $day<=$days_in_month; $day++,$weekday++){
        if($weekday == 7){
            $weekday   = 0; #start a new week
            $calendar .= "</tr>\n<tr>";
        }
        if(isset($days[$day]) and is_array($days[$day])){
            @list($link, $classes, $content) = $days[$day];
            if(is_null($content))  $content  = $day;
            $calendar .= '<td'.($classes ? ' class="'.htmlspecialchars($classes).'">' : '>').
                ($link ? '<a href="'.htmlspecialchars($link).'">'.$content.'</a>' : $content).'</td>';
        }
        else 

        $calendar .= "<td bgcolor='#F5F5F5' align='center' data-semana=''><center><font size='2px'/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][dia]' value=$day> $day <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][OpcaoA]' value='Peq. Almoço'> Peq. Almoço <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço'> Almoço <br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoB]' value='Almoço Dieta'> Almoço (Dieta)<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoC]' value='Lanche'> Lanche<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoD]' value='Jantar'> Jantar<br />
        <input type='checkbox' name='arrachar[$day][opcaoD]' value='Jantar Dieta'> Jantar (Dieta)</font></center></td>";

    }
    if($weekday != 7) $calendar .= '<td colspan="'.(7-$weekday).'">&nbsp;

    </td>'; #remaining "empty" days

    return $calendar."</tr>\n</table>\n";
}

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');

    $dates = date('Y/m/d');
    $hoje = getdate(strtotime($dates)); 


    //Monta o calendário
    if(isset($_POST["data"])){

        list($dia, $mes, $ano) = explode('/', $_POST["data"]);
        echo generate_calendar($ano,$mes,$dia);

    }   else {

        echo generate_calendar($hoje["year"], $hoje["mon"], $hoje["mday"]);
    }

?>
```